# Pure CSS submenu causing li's to pile on top of each other

Tags: css, submenu

I am modifying a Koken theme for my website and need the navigation to have a submenu. I've gotten it to work with CSS except that when the submenu appears, it pushes the rest of the content down. I added absolute positioning to the submenu li's to prevent this from happening which makes it work the way it is supposed to, except that now the li's are piled up on top of each other. I know Koken is relatively new but if anyone has any suggestions or thoughts, I'd appreciate it...

The url is http://gatesman.com/portfolio/albums/landscapes/

Here is the HTML

```
<nav>
<ul class="k-nav-list k-nav-root "><li><a target="" title="Reel" href="http://gatesman.com">Reel</a></li>
<li><a class="k-nav-set" data-koken-internal title="Portfolio" href="/portfolio/sets/portfolio/">Portfolio</a>
<ul class="k-nav-list "><li><a data-koken-internal title="Cars" href="/portfolio/albums/cars/">Cars</a></li>
<li><a data-koken-internal title="Lifestyle" href="/portfolio/albums/lifestyle/">Lifestyle</a></li>
<li><a class="k-nav-current" data-koken-internal title="Landscapes" href="/portfolio/albums/landscapes/">Landscapes</a></li>
</ul></li><li><a target="" title="About" href="http://gatesman.com/about/">About</a></li>
<li><a target="" title="Blog" href="http://gatesman.com/gatesman-blog/">Blog</a></li>
<li><a target="" title="Contact" href="http://gatesman.com/contact/">Contact</a></li></ul>  </nav>
```

and the corresponding CSS

```
nav li
{
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  line-height: 2;
}

nav ul li
{
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-image: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

nav ul li ul li {
display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul li {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;

}



nav ul li ul li {
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The hiding and absolute positioning should be on the sub `ul`s, not the `li`s.

```
nav ul ul { display: none; position: absolute; /* ...etc... */ }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GrE9/).

Other changes:

```
nav li { display: inline-block; /* ... */ }
```

becomes

```
nav > ul > li { display: inline-block; /* ... */ }
```

and

```
nav ul li:hover > ul li { position: absolute; display: block; }
```

becomes

```
nav ul li:hover > ul { display: block; }
```

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if you deem it the solution.